# Special EditText. Must show a list of occurrences of words starting with the characters entered by the user

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to find a implementation of Intelligent EditText. This EditText must be connected with a hastable of strings.

When the users enters a new character, the edittext must search on the hastable and shows a list of the occurrences of words starting with the same characters the user has entered.

This kind of edit text haves a name? i can't find implementations of this because i dont know the name of this kind of edit text.

Comment: [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).